# Who created the dungeon?

Tags: danmachi

So gods didnt create the dungeon, because they send adventurers to fight monsters in it. But then who created the dungeon?

Comment: I'm pretty sure one of the big exposition dumps does say that the gods created the dungeon as part of their agreement to come down and live with the mortals. They're playing a sort of game where instead of doing godly things they train up their familias and send them into the dungeon to show how good they are.

Comment: It is said many time in the books that the dungeon was around long before the gods came down and there is much they don't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I think the dungeon is an existence created by the world will to force civilisations and races to evolve and constantly improve. That is my assumption. The Gods however are in no way possible involved in the creation of something that hates them and seeks their destruction. You have to remember that the dungeon is not controlled by the gods in anyway or form. Corruption happens everywhere meaning that the gods would seek to use the dungeon for their own benefits if it is controlled by them. Gods in DanMachi have desires, both pure(positive.) and dark(negative.).